# Deal with media queries in CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have this kind of problem:

There's two media queries in my css file which are applied by the height of viewport because width is same on both phones but, i have an input in my html so when i click on it and open the keyboard, viewport height decreases and the second query is applied too. Here's the snippet.
I want first query to be applied on iphone 5 regardless the keyboard is opened or not.

```css
#div{
  height: 20px;
}

@media(max-height: 568px) and (max-width: 320px){
  /*e.g iphone 5*/
  #div{
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@media(max-height: 480px) and (max-width: 320px){
  /*e.g iphone 4*/
  #div{
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Responsive</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <input id="inp"/>
  <div id="div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also add this in your media querys `only screen` i think it will fix your problem

Comment: @xmaster I think the problem is that the screen dimensions change when the keyboard comes up. Does `only screen` somehow account for that?

Comment: @D_N I thought it was

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: can you add a picture?

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me are you sure you are resizing your browser to the correct size?